# WebView external site won't get past loading screen (will not load)

Tags: android, audio, webview, android-mediaplayer

I'm using the webView in android to try and make one of my favourite websites even better. The site is [patatap.com](http://www.patatap.com/), however I've been having some trouble it seems like my app won't load any assets or data past the loading screen and it just gets stuck at 0% forever. I assume there should be a simple fix to this hopefully someone can help me out, chrome loads it fine.

[image: (getting stuck)]

Here is my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private WebView webView;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(
              View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE);

    webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
    //webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

    //HTML5 stuff
    WebSettings webViewSettings = webView.getSettings();
    webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient(){}); //just added this
    webViewSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
    webViewSettings.setAppCacheEnabled(true);
    //webViewSettings.setDatabaseEnabled(true);

    //webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    //webView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);

    webView.loadUrl("http://www.patatap.com");

}
```